# How much internal space is needed to install an app from the Android Market?

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I have an app in the Android Market which is just shy of the 50 mb limit. It is set to install to the SD card, but one user is getting an "insufficient space on the device" error when he tries to download it from the market. My researched has shown that the market caches some data   onto the internal storage when downloading/installing an app, even if it installs to the SD card.

Is there any way of knowing how much internal storage a user needs to install the app from the market? It doesn't require the full 50 mb app to be downloaded to the internal storage before installing on the SD card, does it?

Comment: I think in the Manage Applications settings it might tell you how much is stored internally as opposed to on SD. As for whether or not it needs the full amount of space at install time even if its going to shift it to the SD, I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be very surprised if this were the case. What device does the user have?

Comment: He has an LG Optimus S. He has 1.3 gb on his SD Card, and 17 mb internal available. I already had him clear his market cache to see if that did anything; no luck. I don't want to ask him to just blindly move as much stuff from internal to SD as he can to free up room...

Comment: I would guess that this is your culprit then. If you can go to a carrier store near you with live demo's and see if you are able to install the app on the same kind of device? It also be possible that there is an application size limit that is enforced on this specific device. Do you know for sure if anyone has been able to install your app on that device?